# Float object is not callable python

Tags: python

I have a simple script trying to calculate the area and circumference of a circle. On the first iteration of the loop, it works just fine. However, on the second it breaks saying "'float' object is not callable". Any ideas on what is wrong?

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Google Drive/School/Spring 2015/Scripting/ITD2313-Portfolio-GandyBrandon/Assignments/Hands-on & Labs/Question1.py", line 16, in <module>
    area = area(radius)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

**Code:**

```
import math
finished = False
def area(number):
    area = math.pi * (number**2)
    return area
def circum(number):
    c = 2 * math.pi * number
    return c
while (finished == False):
    radius = 0
    radius = int(input("Please input the radius: "))
    if radius <= 0:
        print ("Exitting the program...")
        finished = True
    else:   
        area = area(radius)
        circum = circum(radius)
        print (area)    
        print (circum)
```

Comment: You have variables named `area` and `circum`, and functions with the same name. Don't do that. Also, next time, please post the ***full text*** of the error or traceback, as it points directly to where the error is occurring.

Comment: Not answering your question, but your variable `finished` is a boolean. You should not explicitly write `while finished == False`, you can just use the boolean itself, like this: `while finished` or `while ! finished`.

Comment: @JNevens I tried that syntax by Python was not having it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the function definition:

You're setting

```
area = area(radius)
circum = circum(radius)
```

and in the second loop you're going to do the same and so on. Change the name of the function to something like `calculate_area` or `calculateArea` and similarly for `circum` (i.e. `calculate_circum` or `calculateCircum`) to avoid such confusions.

Comment: No problem. You should generally try to stick to rules when naming objects in general, you'll see that you'll face such problem less frequently and it will save you time.